# Errors 5XX for RAM Usage problems when querying the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having problems with [this website](https://preparadoroposicionesgeografiahistoria.es) In there I have installed a WordPress with an LMS Plugin (LearnPress) since a year ago. Now, for the last 1 or 2 months, I start getting error 500 randomly in any part of the website in both front and backend, first it was just a few errors, but every week more and more often.

Looking at the error log, I get two different errors:

Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2128

Line 2128 says:

```
// Return number of rows affected.
            $return_val = $this->rows_affected;
        } else {
            $num_rows = 0;
            if ( $this->use_mysqli && $this->result instanceof mysqli_result ) {
2128            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {
                    $this->last_result[ $num_rows ] = $row;
                    $num_rows++;
                }
            } elseif ( is_resource( $this->result ) ) {
                while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {
                    $this->last_result[ $num_rows ] = $row;
                    $num_rows++;
                }
            }
```

And the second error I get often:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41943040 bytes) in /wp-includes/option.php on line 295

Line 295 says:

```
$alloptions = array();
        foreach ( (array) $alloptions_db as $o ) {
295         $alloptions[ $o->option_name ] = $o->option_value;
        }
```

I did a lot of stuff trying to solve it:

- Increase the memory limit
- Migrate the website to a VPS (it was in a shared hosting before)
- Bypass Cloudflare so the website loads directly
- Deactivate all the plugins
- Update the php version, install all its modules, update and downgrade wordpress and all the plugins
- Roll back the website using a backup 1 month old

None of them have been useful, the site is still returning a lot of 5XX errors. I guess there is some action when getting info from the database that generates too many queries and consumes all the memory resources, but I have no idea on how to identify the root of the error.

Comment: `I did a lot of stuff trying to solve it: - Deactivate all the plugins` <- Including LearnPress? And if yes, this issue persisted even after LearnPress was deactivated as well?

Comment: Yes with all plugins deactivated, LearnPress included. And still lots of error 500

Comment: One more thing you could try is temporarily switching to a default WordPress theme (twenty-* theme) and see if that stops the 5XX errors. If it doesn't, then it's most probably a database-related issue as you suspected and I would suggest you use Linux commands like the table of processes (top) command to analyse your server.

Comment: Note that on the second error it's trying to allocate 40MB to copy a single option value. That smells bad. It may be as simple as junk in your trunk.